# Trying to Compile files into a working .apk file: Gives error that AndroidManifest.xml is malformed Binary

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation, xml-parsing, android-manifest

At first I was learning to build a linux app. I used to compile everthing myself bit by bit and then pack the file like .rpm
Now I jumped to Android. I tried developing a Hello World! app. See the structure of code files in Android app and then downloaded Sdk's for my project, these are all command line, from the official website of Android Studio. First compile my MainActivity.kt file: Downloaded the platform (android-33) and then specify other .aar dependencies in the -classpath flag of kotlinc. It compiles fine to the .class file. Then use the d8 command from the build-tools and generate the classes.dex file. Now create the typical structure for my app and write the AndroidManifest.xml file. Zip the compiled files (Not compiling AndroidManifest.xml), someone said should be just as is in the text format. But the apksigner warns me that you Manifest file is malformed.
Then I did an experiment, steal the AndroidManifest.xml from a working apk file (not my apk just from random git project release). I placed the file, I know it doesn't make sense but this time warning goes off. The apk Parser sees no errors and installs the app (atleast installs).

Tried using another project's manifest and the parser doesn't give errors.
Note that my manifest doesn't seem to have syntax errors. Even if some resources are not found, it should install the apk just like when it did with other project's manifest. I believe that while packaging the files to .apk android studio changes the format of the AndroidManifest.xml but my problem is I don't know how to change into that format too.
I don't use any scripts like gradle, i just collect everything myself and compile and then sign the apk.
Please help with this, I'm very close